# jQuery/Javascript will chaining be the solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

dummy.html:

```
<button id="do">Do</button>
```

external.js:

```
$("#do").click(function() {
  history.go(-1);
  alert('One page back');
  history.go(1);
  alert('back from were you started');
});
```

Will execute history.go(-1); and end.

In the final usage scenario it will be used with jQuery UI tabs consisting
of several tabs, and normally history.go(-1) will stay on same page but
normally return to another tab, on the same page.

Can I solve this with chaining and how would it look like?

Answer (score 2):

`history.go(...)` **leaves** the current page and any js running on it will stop.

Comment: @vbd what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Is there an alternate command to history.go to achieve the same for e.g. a two step submit form where step one is submitted and I will go back to modify values before I resubmit and finally submit?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might help you. This uses an array to push/pop a history for the tabs.

http://jsfiddle.net/wgxjz/6/

Edit: It's not bulletproof, but it's something to go on.